# Loyalty in Blade Runner 2049

Tags: plot-explanation, blade-runner-2049

In Blade Runner 2049, none of the characters really have any meaningful "human" connections between each other, which begs the question:

> Is there any evidence of genuine loyalty between the characters in Blade Runner 2049?

I was watching the bonus features of the Blu-Ray and Jared Leto (Niander Wallace) says, "Luv is loyalty personified."

What does he actually mean?

[Link to part of the video when he says this](https://youtu.be/4pp-FyGqUkU?t=198)

Comment: It could be something connected to the fact, that she was a replicant, and Wallace could have bred her especially to super loyal